# Is there a way to import a widget that is written in a different programming language?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I recently came across [this](https://github.com/phastmike/vala-circular-progress-bar) Github page which provides a nice circular progress bar that i would like to use, but its written in Vala and i use Python for my app currently.
Is there a way to use it even that i use a different programming language ?
I've tried to see how they coded the progress bars and i cant seem to understand it sadly (i tried recreating it).

Personally i don't mind learning Vala but python is much easier to make apps with and its simple as hell.

Comment: What exactly you can't understand in this implementation? There are 4 important methods (`get_request_mode`, `get_preferred_width`/`get_preferred_height` and `draw`), i.e. everything below [line 130](https://github.com/phastmike/vala-circular-progress-bar/blob/master/circular-progress-bar.vala#L130) Other methods are just setters/getters. `draw` just draws circles and arcs.

Answer (score 2):

You could also compile the Vala code into a library, and process it using GObject introspection. That would generate a module that you could import using `from gi.repository import CircularProgress` (or whatever you decide to call it).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic example in Python:

https://gist.github.com/benreu/18dea8afc7c2ce75aae5297f6096d657

I may update the setters and getters part, if I find the time.